# Python import module error

Tags: python, import

I have a problem in import of modules in my project. I was creating tests and I cant import my main to test one end point of my application, from the test file `teste_ex.py`. This is my project structure:

```
backend_api/
    api/
        __init__.py
        main.py
    testes/
        __init__.py
        test_ex.py
```

In my test_ex.py Im trying to import `main` in this way:

```
import api.main
from webtest import TestApp

def test_functional_concursos_api():
    app = TestApp(main.app)
    assert app.get('/hello').status == '200 OK'
```

I omly get `ImportError: No module named 'api'`

- What can be done to import my main to my test file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's my best guess as to what might help:

You should make sure that the path to the directory in which your `main.py` file resides can be found in `sys.path`.  You can check this yourself by running this snippet in `test_ex.py`:

```
import sys

for line in sys.path:
    print line
```

If the directory in which `main.py` is found is *not* included in your `path`, you can append that path to `sys.path`, like this (include this snippet in `test_ex.py`):

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/path/to/your/module/backendapi/api/")
```