# Don't understand cause of this ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, python-import

I have a file structure as follows:

```
└── project    
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── main.py
    └── package1
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── module1 
        └── subpackage
            ├── __init__.py
            └── module2.py
```

module2 contains a function called A, and module 1 imports module2 with the code:

```
from subpackage import module2
```

this works fine when running module1 directly, but when I then try to import module1 from main.py, I get an error. The code for the import statement in main.py is

```
from package1 import module1
```

this gives the error

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...\project\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from package1 import module1
  File "C:\...\project\package1\module1.py", line 1, in <module>
    from subpackage import module2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'subpackage'
```

I don't really understand what is happening here, I tried changing the current working directory with os.chdir() to package2 in module1, but this had no effect. Upon researching the problem, the only thing I could find that might relate to my problem was absolute vs relative imports, but changing the import statements didn't effect the error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python import module error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39813581/python-import-module-error)

Comment: There is no `package1` in your file structure.

Comment: thanks, that was a typo, I do have a package1 in the actual project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `module1.py` file you need to provide full path (absolute) for the imported file. So if you want to run your code from the `main.py` file you need to change your import in the `module1.py` to:

```
from package2.subpackage import module2
```

or

```
import package2.subpackage.module2
```

Comment: Thanks, I came across this solution but thought it failed as it doesn't work when running 'module2.py' directly.